# c++: Program crashes with parameter (by value) passed to a lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, callback, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I simplified the code, so pardon my style.

I was wondering what happens to an object that is constructed by a constructor that actually allocates memory, and passed to a lambda by value, when this lambda itself, is being a callback by another thread.
It didn't surprise me to see the program crashes when the destructor is called. This was **test#1**.

**test#2**: I removed the "new" and the "delete[]" from c'tor and d'tor of A, and now - it worked fine.

**test#3**:
I brought the "new" and the "delete[]" back as before, but now I changed every place with "A objA" (by value) into "A& objA", and now, it didn't crash as well.

Now, I can rationalize it by waving my hands but I'd like to understand what really happened here, and for that matter - what would happen if an object that is passed into a lambda by "capture", also ceases to exist.

and last question: is there a good practice or tip what to do (or what to avoid) in such cases?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class A {
public:
    A() : x(1) { ptr = new char[1024]; }
    ~A() { delete[](ptr); }
    int getX() { return x; }
private:
    int x = 0;
    char* ptr = nullptr;
};

std::function<void(A objA)> myCb;

int myThread()
{
    static int counter = 0;
    auto a = new A;
    while (true) {
        
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
        if (myCb)
            myCb(*a);
        else
            std::cout << "myCb is still NULL: counter = " << counter << std::endl;

        if (counter++ == 5)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

void registerCallback(std::function<void(A obj)> cb)
{
    myCb = cb;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(myThread);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(6s);
    int val = 5;
    registerCallback([&val](A objA) {
        std::cout << "here lambda is called with " << objA.getX() << " and " << val << std::endl;
        });

    val = 6;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    val = 7;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    val = 8;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    t1.join();
}
```

Comment: I don't imagine assigning to a `std::function` while reading from it in another thread is allowed without syncyhronization.

Answer (score 2):

`class A` is violating the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), as it does not implement a copy-constructor and/or move-constructor, or a copy-assignment and/or move-assignment operator.

So, when an instance of `A` is passed around *by value*, a **shallow copy** is made that shares the same `char*` pointer to a single `char[]` array in memory, and thus the code MAY crash (ie, *undefined behavior*) when trying to `delete[]` that same array multiple times.

What you need is a **deep copy** instead, so that each instance of `A` allocates its own `char[]` array, eg:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    A() : x(1), ptr(new char[1024])
    {
        std::fill(ptr, ptr + 1024, '\0');
    }

    A(const A &src) : x(src.x), ptr(new char[1024])
    {
        std::copy(src.ptr, src.ptr + 1024, ptr);
    }

    A(A &&src)
        : x(src.x), ptr(src.ptr)
    {
        src.ptr = nullptr;
    }

    ~A()
    {
        delete[] ptr;
    }

    A& operator=(A rhs)
    {
        std::swap(x, rhs.x);
        std::swap(ptr, rhs.ptr);
        return *this;
    }

    int getX() const { return x; }

private:
    int x;
    char* ptr;
};
```

A simpler way to implement this is to use `std::vector` instead of `new[]`, since `vector` is already compliant with the Rule of 3/5/0, and so compiler-generated constructors, destructor, and assignment operators for `A` will suffice to make copies/moves of the `vector` for you, eg:

```cpp
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
    A() : vec(1024, '\0') {}

    int getX() const { return x; }

private:
    int x = 1;
    std::vector<char> vec;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use unique_ptr. deleting a void* is undefined behavior

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class A {
public:
    A() : x(1)
    {       
        ptr = std::make_unique<char[]>(1024);
    }
    ~A()
    {
    }
    int getX() { return x; }
private:
    int x = 0;
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> ptr = nullptr;
};

std::function<void(A& objA)> myCb;

int myThread()
{
    static int counter = 0;
    auto a = new A;
    while (true) {

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
        if (myCb)
            myCb(*a);
        else
            std::cout << "myCb is still NULL: counter = " << counter << std::endl;

        if (counter++ == 5)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

void registerCallback(std::function<void(A& obj)> cb)
{
    myCb = cb;
}

int mymain()
{
    std::thread t1(myThread);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(6s);
    int val = 5;
    registerCallback([&val](A& objA) {
        std::cout << "here lambda is called with " << objA.getX() << " and " << val << std::endl;
    });

    val = 6;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    val = 7;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    val = 8;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    t1.join();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I cannot see where in the asker's code they `delete`ed a `void*`

Comment: the code got rewritten oginaly ptr was declared as void*